# Не могу вызвать метод в тернарном операторе

Tags: c#

```
public static double Foo(double x, double a, double b)
{
    a < b ? Console.WriteLine(a) : Console.WriteLine(b);
    return Math.Cos(2 * x) + Math.Sin(x - 3);
}
```

Что мешает в тернарном операторе вызвать метод `Console.WriteLine()`, и как было бы правильно? Вылезает ошибка:

> В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения назначения, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создания нового объекта

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(a < b ? a : b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что он возвращает void, а тернарный оператор является выражением.

```
Console.WriteLine(a < b ? a : b);
```